# Ruby compile failed while installing on Mountain Lion 10.8?

Tags: ruby, installation, osx-mountain-lion

This is the command I entered in the terminal while following "[Ruby on Rails development with Mac OS X Mountain Lion](http://createdbypete.com/articles/ruby-on-rails-development-with-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/)", and its result:

```
rbenv install 2.0.0-p247

Downloading openssl-1.0.1e.tar.gz...
    -> https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1e.tar.gz
    Installing openssl-1.0.1e...

BUILD FAILED

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/x8/19f_wwjx4gd26z6qdq874tj40000gs/T/ruby-build.20130919211135.42003
    Results logged to /var/folders/x8/19f_wwjx4gd26z6qdq874tj40000gs/T/ruby-    build.20130919211135.42003.log

    Last 10 log lines:
    RANLIB        =true
    ARFLAGS       =
    PERL          =/usr/bin/perl
    SIXTY_FOUR_BIT_LONG mode
    DES_UNROLL used
    DES_INT used
    RC4 uses uchar
    RC4_CHUNK is unsigned long
    sh: make: command not found
    /usr/local/bin/ruby-build: line 387: make: command not found
```

Please help!

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with Rails. It *would* have if the installation of Ruby succeeded.

Comment: True, But how to get rails installed have become concern for me. Referring multiple blogs but none of them proved to be of any help.

Comment: Are you sure you installed the xCode Command Line Tools?  It looks like it's not able to find 'make' to compile the source.

Comment: While we understand your goal is to install Rails, the task at hand is to get Ruby installed, which is what your question is really about. When you create questions, be specific; Your intention to install Rails is just a data-point but isn't useful. Data that isn't useful needs to be left out as it can distract, and makes us wade though inconsequential information to get at the gist of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/local/bin/ruby-build: line 387: make: command not found` means rbenv can't compile Ruby because the necessary tools aren't available.

1. Have you installed Xcode?
2. Have you installed its associated command-line applications? That's the second step needed, and is found inside the Xcode application.
3. Have you recently updated Xcode? If so, you might need to update [the command-line tools](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode%20-#) too.

Comment: Xcode is installed but not the Command-Line Applications. I am installing it right now.

Comment: Yes it worked after installing " Command-Line Applications" .
Thanks for the help the Tin Man , Helios de Guerra.